# Stop FooTable from stripping html from <td> tags when converting cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, footable

I'm using FooTable (http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html) to create some dynamic tables from my static html tables.

Within the table's cells or  tags are html to format the value in the cell. For example I use bootstraps label component in one cell.

The problem I'm having is that when the footable runs it converts all the html formating and seems to strip all these html tags from the cells and I'm just left with the text.

So for example I may have in one cell:

```
<td><span class="label label-default">Default</span></td>
```

Converts over to:

```
<td>Default</td>
```

My question is there an option to stop this from happening? I have search Google and on the footable documentation but I'm having no luck.

It seems that not a lot of people have had this problem. But surely someone knows if it is possible or not.

Comment: have you find solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to identify the columns as HTML, using `data-type="html"` in the column that has HTML.

Example:

```
            <table id="testTable" class="table" data-paging="true">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 45%">Origin</th>
                    <th data-breakpoints="sm xs" style="width: 45%">Destination</th>
                    <th style="width: 5%" data-type="html">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>O1</td>
                    <td>D1</td>
                    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>O2</td>
                    <td>D2</td>
                    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>O3</td>
                    <td>D3</td>
                    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#testTable").footable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating your own formatter?

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable({
        "columns": [{
            "formatter": function(value){
                return value;
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

It seems a bit redundant, but it does have a default "type" formatter so perhaps just passing the value straight back without any additional uknown sorcery will fix the issue.